# creating a load more posts button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, pagination

I am trying to create a load more posts button on my wordpress site.  I want 15 posts to show at first, and then after ever 15 posts the load more button appears, loading 15 posts at a time.  I also want the load more button to disappear if there are no more posts left to load.  With the code below, I've been able to add the button.  However, at first no posts appear on my site and then when I press the button 15 load, but then the button disappears.  How could I fix this, and make the load more button work effectively?

frontpage.php

```html
<?php 
/* 
* Template Name: 
*/ 

get_header(); 
get_template_part ('inc/carousel'); 

$the_query = new WP_Query( [ 
'posts_per_page' => 15, 
'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) 
] ); 

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?> 
<div id="ajax"> 
<?php 
$i = 0; 
$j = 0; 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post(); 

if ( $i % 5 === 0 ) { // Large post: on the first iteration and every 7th post after... ?> 
<div class="row"> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-12 col-md-12' ); ?>> 
<div class="large-front-container"> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
</div> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a> 
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?> 
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?> 
<div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
</div> 
</article> 
</div> 

<?php 

} else { // Small posts ?> 
<?php if($j % 2 === 0) echo '<div class="row">'; ?> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
    <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
    </div>

</article> 

<?php $j++; if($j % 2 === 0) echo '</div>'; ?> 
<?php 
} 
$i++; 
}?> 

</div> 
 <div class="loadmore">Load More</div>
<?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) { 
} 
} 
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') { 
echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>'; 
} 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
get_footer();
```

loadmore-posts.js

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".post").addClass("hide"); 
        total = jQuery( ".post" ).length;
            x = 15;

        jQuery('.loadmore').click(function () {
           //y = x;
            jQuery(total);
        jQuery(".post").removeClass("hide");     
            jQuery(".post:gt("+x+")").addClass("hide"); 
         x++;


        if(x >= total){
        jQuery( ".loadmore" ).hide();
        }

        });

    });
```